# How to send Node js data directly to HTML page

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, firebase, bundle

I have a node js code like this

```
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
const serviceAccount = require("C:/Users/santo/Downloads/bestmpos-firebase-adminsdk.json");

admin.initializeApp({
 credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount)
});
async function start (object){
  const info = await fs.collection('users').doc(object.uid).get();
  if (!info.exists) {
    console.log('No document');
   } else {
    console.table(object.uid, [info.data()]);

   }
}
```

I wanted to print `console.table(object.uid, [info.data()])` in the HTML page with  directy without hosting server, I just simply want to render the data in a html page directly

I need  tag out of this directly,
Which dependency should I use to get this?

Comment: [The Admin SDK is a set of server libraries that lets you interact with Firebase from privileged environments](https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup). You can't use it directly from the browser.

Comment: @quentin all I need is to display the data, Can I do it with browserify?